# ngStyle goes into infinite loop if bind a function

Tags: angular

In Angular when I bind a function to `[ngStyle]` directive it goes into inifinite loop. I put debugger in it to detect it. I think, this impacts the performance of the app. Why does it happen and can I avoid it?

```
// html 
 <div [ngStyle]="getStyles()"></div>

// js
getStyles() {
    debugger;
    return {background: 'red'};
  }
```

Comment: Easiest way to avoid it: Use CSS for styling your elements instead of inlining them

Comment: it is because the ngStyle check for value change so it is better to use a css class with condition for different style value

Comment: When you say infinite, did you actually count how many times you go in it ? If it's more than 10 then okay, but it can be called several times because the change detection happens several times. It doesn't seem that you trigger a change detection bt sending a hard-coded object, but I might be wrong, so could you confirm that for me please ?

Comment: @hana_wujira Can't use class, because I am working with backround property. I have to put url dynamicly in it :(

Comment: @trichetriche It is actually infinite, does not stop

Comment: And if you use a getter, does it makes the same infinite loop ?

Comment: what do u mean by _I have to put url dynamically in it_

Comment: @MichaelKutateladze Which background property you want to use ?

Comment: @MichaelKutateladze And you can also give background property in class. And for that you can use ngClass. Pelase try to implement my answer. And give comment still if you faced any issue. :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<div [ngClass]="{'changeColor' : flag}" (click)="ok()"></div>
```

In your .ts file

```
flag : any = false;

ok(){
   flag : true;
}
```

In your css

```
::ng-deep .changeColor{
    background: 'red'
}
```

Comment: @Michael Kutateladze Can you please update your status on issue and answer ?